# Laravel filter posts based on users with dropdown menu

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I want to create a dropdown menu where you can filter between different posts based on users. So for example you have a dropdown menu with User 1 and User 2. When you select user 1 you get all the posts made by that user. This is the code I used:

In my UserController

```js
 public function filter($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $posts = $user->posts()->get();

        $posts = User::with('posts')->find($id)->$posts;

        return view('posts.filter', compact('posts'));
    }
```

In my web.php

```js
Route::get('/filter/{id}', [UserController::class, 'filter'])->name('users.filter');
```

In my filter.blade.php

```js
<div class =container">
    <select name="" id="" onchange="location = this.value;">
        @foreach ($users as $user)
            <option value="/user/{{$user->id}}"> {{$user->email}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

If I go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/filter/1 I get the following error: ErrorException
Undefined variable: users (View: /Users/mich/Desktop/school/Jaar2_CMGT/Programmeren5_Frameworks /Laravel_Project/resources/views/posts/filter.blade.php)

Comment: return view('posts.filter', compact('posts'));, You are passing posts so you need to use $posts instead of $users.

Comment: You don't pass `$users` to your view. In your view you could check if `$users` is set and if it is, display the `<select>...`